# Start command multiple times in Excel using Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command in a custom tab in my spreadsheet. I want to start this command more than one time with different conditions in my spreadsheet, i.e. a cell changes for every time i want to run the command. The results are written in new sheets named after the cell's value accordingly.

To run the command from a Macro i put it in the Quick Access Toolbar.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "2"
Application.SendKeys "%4"
ActiveCell.Value = "3"
Application.SendKeys "%4"
ActiveCell.Value = "4"
Application.SendKeys "%4"
```

Only the last SendKeys command runs. Wait will only delay and not make it work.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 0):

VBA has built-in listeners for events such as cell changes. For example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

You can use something like this to run your macro each time a change is made. You will usually also need to disable the listening while it is running or you'll create an endless loop :)